# Spring mvc filter for some controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I need to process all request coming to some Spring controllers to get some requester informartion or to throw exceptions like a security filter.

I would like if is there something buildin in Spring like a filter for controllers (I need it not for all controller, but only for someone).
I don't want to apply this filter by url request but with a class/method extension or annotation.

This is my actual solution:

```
@Controller
public class MyFilteredController extends FilterController {

    @RequestMapping("/filtered")
    public void test1(HttpServletRequest req){
        InfoBean infobean=filter(req);
        //... controller job
    }

}
```

A controller that extends a class with a filter method.

```
public abstract FilterController{
    protected InfoBean filter(HttpServletRequest req){
        //... filter job
        return infobean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> I don't want to apply this filter by url request but with a
>   class/method extension or annotation

You can register a `HandlerInterceptor` for this purpose. For example, you can apply a filter to all handler methods that annotated with `SomeAnnotation` with following code:

```
public class CustomHandlerIntercepter extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;

            SomeAnnotation annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(SomeAnnotation.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, you should register your interceptor in `WebConfig`:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new CustomHandlerIntercepter());
    }
}
```

You can read more about interceptors in [spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-interceptors).

Comment: "//do stuff" also means to link spring beans like @ Services?

Comment: If you want to have access to spring managed component and services, you should make this interceptor a `Component` and `Autowire` them into interceptor.

Comment: Ok, nice! And last thing, can I access handlerMethod params?

Comment: `handlerMethod.getMethodParameters()` http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SpringSandwich http://springsandwich.com/

It lets you set filters (Spring Interceptors, actually) directly as controller annotations.  Unlike normal servlet filters, you'll also have full access to your Spring context.

Disclosure: I'm the author of this framework :)

Comment: SpringSandwich seems like a better approach than the others. Code is more organized.Thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I access @RequestParam attribute inside sandwich filter class

Comment: @HeisenBerg how about req.getParameter("my-param")

Answer (score 0):

Everything in using the SpringDispatcherServlet is URL based, I don't think you can do it by controller.

You will need to use a Filter, looks at the API here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/package-summary.html  you will probable want to use a OncePerRequestFilter.

```
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

you will then need to add the filter in the web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>requestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.greg.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>errorHandlerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Now the hacky bit, if you want to get Spring beans in here you can create a Bridge class with statics in it.

```
public class Bridge {

    private static PaymentService paymentService;

    public PaymentService getPaymentService() {
        return paymentService;
    }

    public void setPaymentService(PaymentService paymentService) {
        Bridge.paymentService = paymentService;
    }

}
```

If you want to inject some spring beans into this class

```
<bean id="paymentService" class="net.isban.example.service.PaymentService" />

    <bean class="net.isban.example.util.Bridge">
        <property name="paymentService" ref="paymentService" />
    </bean>
```

Then in your filter (not spring class).

```
PaymentService paymentService = new Bridge().getPaymentService();
```

Happy for someone to show me a less hacky way of doing this.

Comment: I cannot use a filter like this because I need some spring context objects  like @ Service, @ Repository etc. This is why I want a filter inside a controller.

Comment: @Tobia please read my answer, I have specifically shown you how to get beans into your filter via the Bridge class, which bridges from the non spring (filter) to the spring container (@Service etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvc intercepters here .

see : 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

and if you want to intercept particular url you can do it as specified here

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors